# iOS swift socket communication: release outstream

Tags: ios, swift, sockets

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/3437391-real-time-communication-with-streams-tutorial-for-ios) to make the most simple socket communication just to exchange string messages. However, when I write to the outstream, it seems to be never released until I kill the app - then the server receives everything in one chunk. I searched for solutions and found similar questions and problems, without solution. Here is my code:

```
class Peer: NSObject {
  weak var delegate: PeerDelegate?
  var inputStream: InputStream!
  var outputStream: OutputStream!

  var username = ""
  let maxReadLength = 4096

func setupNetworkCommunication() {
  var readStream: Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
  var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?

  CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault,"192.168.43.1" as CFString,6000,&readStream,&writeStream)
  inputStream = readStream!.takeRetainedValue()
  outputStream = writeStream!.takeRetainedValue()
  inputStream.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .common)
  outputStream.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .common)
  inputStream.open()
  outputStream.open()

  inputStream.delegate = self


}
    func sendText(text: String) {
      print("Sending", text)
      let data = text.data(using: .utf8)!
        data.withUnsafeBytes {
        guard let pointer = $0.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self) else {
          print("Error sending text")
          return
        }
        outputStream.write(pointer, maxLength: data.count)
        print("DONE")
      }
}
}
```

As you may notice, there is also a delegate that monitors the stream and responds to incoming data. It bothers me that I cannot simply send strings forth and back. It could be on a server side problem, that it waits for more, but if I run it with Android, it just works without extras. I tried to finalize, release and close the stream to produce something similar to an app kill, without success. There seems to be no flush command as in Java. Any ideas where the problem lies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the solution seems to be ending the string with a line-breaker \n